# CVS error: Directory does not exist on server

Tags: cvs, tortoisecvs

I have a .Net MVC project created in **Visual Studio 2010**. We're using **CVS** for source control. I bound the source control through Visiual Studio using **TamTam CVS** and I think that is where the problems began.

I got some errors using **TamTam** so I tried to resolve it by checking it in from Window using **TortoiseCVS** instead. Now, even though most of the project is under source control, some sub-directories are giving errors when I try to add their contents (using TortoiseCVS).

These are the problem folders:

> ```
> Project\Content\themes\base
> Project\Content\themes\base\images
> ```

I get the green CVS check on the `base` folder and on the `base\images` folder. However, when I try to add the contents of these folders into CVS I get:

> cvs [server aborted]: Directory /repositories/location/Project
>   /Project/Project/Content/themes/base
>   does not exist on the server

I tried deleting all the hidden CVS folders from under the `base` and `base\images` directory but now I get this error:

> cvs add: CVSROOT is set but empty!  Make sure that the cvs add:
>   specification of CVSROOT is legal, either via the cvs add: `-d'
>   option, the CVSROOT environment variable, or the cvs [add aborted]:
>   CVS/Root file (if any).
>
> Error, CVS operation failed

What is the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently got the "CVSROOT is set but empty!" error message when using TortoiseCVS 1.12 on Windows. I found that the problem was caused by the fact that my CVS/Root file had Unix-style line endings. When I changed the CVS/Root file so that it has Windows-style line endings, the error message no longer occurs.  The reason why my Root file had Unix-style line endings is because I had checked out the files using cygwin's cvs command instead of TortoiseCVS.